# Does the return value of .then() callback affect original promise in any way?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am reading a book named [You dont know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md). I am at the part where the author is explaining why errors in the `promise.then()`'s success callback isn't designed to be caught in the error callback in the same `promise.then()`. In other words:

```
 somePromise.then(
        function success(msg){
            throw new Error()//Line A
        },
        function error(err){
            //error at Line A will not be caught here
        }
    );
```

Here is the actual content from the book:

```
var p = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( 42 );
} );

p.then(
    function fulfilled(msg){
        foo.bar(); //Line C: will throw error because foo is null
        console.log( msg ); // never gets here :(
    },
    function rejected(err){//Line D
        // never gets here either :(
    }
);
```

> Why couldn't it just call the error handler we have defined there (*he is talking about callback at Line D*)? Seems like a logical behavior on the surface. But it would violate the fundamental principle that Promises are immutable once resolved. p was already fulfilled to the value 42, so it can't later be changed to a rejection just because there's an error in observing p's resolution.

**I have problem with this line:**

*p was already fulfilled to the value 42, so it can't later be changed to a rejection just because there's an error in observing p's resolution.*

IMO, even if the error in Line C would have been designed to be caught in Line D, it wouldn't have any impact on original promise (`p`). Simply because `.then()` will return **a new promise** which is in no way related to original promise. Author seems to think otherwise. IMHO, what they should have said instead:

*When an error is thrown in Line C, a new, rejected `Promise` has been created  so it can't later be given to callback at Line D, since rejected `Promise` is immutable `Promise`.*

Am I missing something here?

Source of content: [link](http://%22https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md%22)

Comment: I did not understand your suggestion. But you are right a new rejected promise is created. And the error handler is on the successful `p` promise.

Comment: Author is explaining the design choise: why rejected promise in success callback isn't handed over to error callback. I think their reasoning is wrong, since the return value of sucess callback isn't doesnt impact the original promise. My reasoning is: since the error in success callback has already created a new immmutable promise, we will achieve nothing by passing it to error callback because its immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confusing. I think the point that the author is trying to make goes like this

1. `rejected` runs if and only if `p` is rejected
2. if an exception in line C were to cause a call to the `rejected` handler, it would need to reject `p` to do that
3. since `p` is immutable and cannot be rejected from a `then` handler on it, it follows that line C cannot cause that call

This is a bit like circular reasoning, because #1 would also follow from our deduction that line C doesn't cause `rejected` to run. We only need to accept #1 as the reasonable design choice.

But yes, your understanding of the matter is [completely fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).